# Miniprofiler for ASP.NET web site

Tags: asp.net, web, mvc-mini-profiler

[image]How can I use miniprofiler in asp.net web site(NOT FOR MVC)? 
There are many resources for MVC but I can not find anything for web site.

Thanks to Alex. Now it works for asp.net web site. But I can not understand what it displays.
I have not written any code in method. See the image below.

Code is as below for which I ran profiler.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("test"))
    {
        Page.Title = "12345";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the [miniprofiler.com](http://miniprofiler.com/):

> PM> Install-Package MiniProfiler

in your `global.asax`:

```
using StackExchange.Profiling;
...    
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.IsLocal)
    {
        MiniProfiler.Start();
    } 
}

protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    MiniProfiler.Stop();
}
```

and then somewhere in your master page:

```
<%= StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes() %>
```

This should be enough for starting.

Comment: Thanks Alex, now I can see the profiler but I can not understand what does it all means. Can you please guide me?
See the code and image that I have attached with edited question.

Comment: @ChiragFanse: by using `MiniProfiler.Current.Step("test")` you're creating a *profile step* called "test". Typically you could put some *heavy logic* into steps, and then see the stats for these steps.

Comment: When I look at where <%= StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes() %> is in the rendered HTML in the browser nothing appears there. But no errors or anything.

Comment: @MatthewLock: are you sure you started MP in the begin request event handler?

Comment: Yes. I even put a breakpoint on it, to confirm that it was being called.

Comment: @Alex : Can you please explain me the purpose of RenderIncludes() method?

Comment: @Ankita: `RenderIncludes` writes out necessary scripts and styles for miniprofiler to show

Comment: @Alex: Thank you. Can you please help me with this question-[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255960/miniprofiler-current-method-does-not-return-the-time]

Comment: Check if runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests is true on your web.config

Comment: I had to install ApplicationInsightsWebTracking for this, why?