# Miniprofiler.Current method does not return the time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler, mvcminiprofiler

I'm trying to get time with this code using `MiniProfiler`.

```
var profiler = StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfiler.Current;
```

But it returns `0 ms` in result. How to get `current time` in miniprofiler.

This method gives me result with `MiniProfiler version 2.1.0.`

Right now I am using `MiniProfiler version 3.1.1.139`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the total elapsed time for the current `MiniProfiler` by accessing `StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfiler.Current.DurationMilliseconds` - but only **after** the current MiniProfiler has been stopped (it is only [populated at that point](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/07c52c4314a9ef52fc0879b247a854c062e58b3d/StackExchange.Profiling/MiniProfiler.cs#L483)). Before it is stopped, an active MiniProfiler instance will not have this property set.

There is no way right now to get the elapsed time for an active MiniProfiler instance. There is an internal property called [`ElapsedTicks`](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/07c52c4314a9ef52fc0879b247a854c062e58b3d/StackExchange.Profiling/MiniProfiler.cs#L226) but as this is an internal property, you cannot access it outside of the MiniProfiler assembly.

If it is super-important for you to be able to access this data for an active MiniProfiler instance, than you could fork the current build and switch the property to be public (though before you do this I would question what your use case is - perhaps there is another way to achieve this).

Comment: Thank You, But I did not find ElapsedTicks method..Please note the version of MiniProfiler is 3.1.1.139

Comment: You are right. `ElapsedTicks` is an internal property. I have corrected my answer. Please see above.