# Steps for profiling SQL related operations in ASP.Net Web application using Mini profiler

Tags: sql, asp.net, miniprofiler

I have seen very good documentation for MVC Mini profiler. But I need similar good documentation for Mini profiler for ASP.Net Web application. 
Please help me in setting up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just google a bit. I have found the following links

1. [Miniprofiler for ASP.NET web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087101/miniprofiler-for-asp-net-web-site)
2. [Using MiniProfiler with ASP.NET WebForms](http://inthecodingzone.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/using-miniprofiler-with-aspnet-webforms.html)

I know the question is about Miniprofiler, but glimpse is also a very good profiler to see what is happening behind the scenes

[Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/)